# C# WebBrowser how to click a button

Tags: c#, class, button, click

I try to make a program and I need to click a button using my program
`webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");`

This doesn't work because this button has no id.
Here is the code of the button:

```
<a class="buttonMtel" tabindex="6" onclick="document.forms['SMSForm'].submit()">
    <span>Изпрати</span>
</a>
<span>Изпрати</span>.
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: If it is default button then you can send "Enter" key. tell me if you want i can post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your button is the only anchor with `class="buttonMtel"`, you could use the [`GetElementByTagName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx) method and then locate the desired element:

```
var anchors = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement anchor in anchors)
{
    if (anchor.GetAttribute("class") == "buttonMtel") 
    {
        // we have found the button => click on it
        anchor.InvokeMember("click");
        break;
    }
}
```

or if you prefer LINQ:

```
var anchor = webBrowser1
    .Document
    .GetElementByTagName("a")
    .Cast<HtmlElement>()
    .FirstOrDefault(anchor => anchor.GetAttribute("class") == "buttonMtel");
if (anchor != null)
{
    anchor.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

If on the other hand you have multiple anchors with `class="buttonMtel"` in your DOM you will need a different approach. Depending on the actual structure of your DOM you might need to first locate some parent element and then reach up to the desired button.

Comment: Ty but here it gives me error   if (anchor.GetAttribute("class") == "buttonMtel")
                {
                    // we have found the button => click on it
                    anchor.InvokeMember("click");
                    break;
                } in anchor there is not GetArttibute or invokeMember

Comment: ok, use `foreach (HtmlElement anchor in anchors)` instead of `foreach (var anchor in anchors)`. I have updated my answer to illustrate this.

Comment: it doesnt work maybe because there are 2 buttons in this class

Comment: Then you will have to identify some unique parent element that contains the desired button. And locate this parent element first. It's hard to be more specific without knowing your DOM structure. On the other hand if you know that your DOM contains 2 such elements you can modify the code so that it selects the second.